# Ansible. Get specific value from {{ item }} loop

Tags: linux, loops, ansible

I'm trying to work with loops and item(s) and I can't get it to work... maybe you can help me.

So I want to print in a loop the "content" value of this output and I'm unable to do this. Do

```
- name: "Verify started instances"
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:808{{ item[-1] }}/url"
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
  register: status
  until: "status is search('Version')"
  retries: 3
  delay: 60
  ignore_errors: yes
  with_items: "{{ instances_running.stdout_lines }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ status }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Output looks like that:

```
TASK [[AppServerAgent] verify started instances] **************************************************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: [AppServerAgent] verify started instances (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [AppServerAgent] verify started instances (2 retries left).
ok: [SERVER] => (item=inst0)
FAILED - RETRYING: [AppServerAgent] verify started instances (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [AppServerAgent] verify started instances (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [AppServerAgent] verify started instances (1 retries left).
failed: [SERVER] (item=instnull) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 3, "changed": false, "item": "instnull", "msg": "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '808l'", "status": -1, "url": "http://localhost:808l/url"}
...ignoring

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [SERVER] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "attempts": 3,
                "changed": false,
                "connection": "close",
                "content": "Version:      2-SNAPSHOT\nBuild number: 1\nBuild id:     2020-11-325_09-03-20\n",
                "content_length": "281",
                "cookies": {},
                "cookies_string": "",
                "date": "",
                "elapsed": 0,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backup": null,
                        "body": null,
                        "body_format": "raw",
                        "client_cert": null,
                        "client_key": null,
                        "content": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "delimiter": null,
                        "dest": null,
                        "directory_mode": null,
                        "follow": false,
                        "follow_redirects": "safe",
                        "force": false,
                        "force_basic_auth": false,
                        "group": null,
                        "headers": {},
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                        "method": "GET",
                        "mode": null,
                        "owner": null,
                        "regexp": null,
                        "remote_src": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "return_content": true,
                        "selevel": null,
                        "serole": null,
                        "setype": null,
                        "seuser": null,
                        "src": null,
                        "status_code": [
                            200
                        ],
                        "timeout": 30,
                        "unix_socket": null,
                        "unsafe_writes": null,
                        "url": "http://localhost:8080/url",
                        "url_password": null,
                        "url_username": null,
                        "use_proxy": true,
                        "validate_certs": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "inst0",
                "msg": "OK (281 bytes)",
                "redirected": false,
                "status": 200,
                "url": "http://localhost:8080/url"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "attempts": 3,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": true,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backup": null,
                        "body": null,
                        "body_format": "raw",
                        "client_cert": null,
                        "client_key": null,
                        "content": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "delimiter": null,
                        "dest": null,
                        "directory_mode": null,
                        "follow": false,
                        "follow_redirects": "safe",
                        "force": false,
                        "force_basic_auth": false,
                        "group": null,
                        "headers": {},
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                        "method": "GET",
                        "mode": null,
                        "owner": null,
                        "regexp": null,
                        "remote_src": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "return_content": true,
                        "selevel": null,
                        "serole": null,
                        "setype": null,
                        "seuser": null,
                        "src": null,
                        "status_code": [
                            200
                        ],
                        "timeout": 30,
                        "unix_socket": null,
                        "unsafe_writes": null,
                        "url": "http://localhost:808l/url",
                        "url_password": null,
                        "url_username": null,
                        "use_proxy": true,
                        "validate_certs": true
                    }
                },
                "item": "instnull",
                "msg": "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '808l'",
                "status": -1,
                "url": "http://localhost:808l/url"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I was trying to use something like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.content.split('\n') }}"
  with_items: "{{ status }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

but then the output looks like that:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [SERVER]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeBytes object' has no attribute 'content'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/deploy.yaml': line 176, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

How can I do this?
Or maybe there is also a way to use other command instead of `until: "status is search('Version')"` to find `content` field and print output in name block instead of debug task?

THanks!

Comment: Change `until: "status is search('Version')"` to `until: "status.content is search('Version')"`

Comment: It still works as a previous solution. It means I can still validate Version from the output, but it doesn't show output itself. So this is just a different approach of validation but the result is this same.

Comment: `with_items: "{{ status.results }}"` since your `status` is registered from a loop.

Comment: I do not get it. Can you please post code? Because I think you are talking about debug section, right?

Comment: `- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.content.split('\n') }}"
  with_items: "{{ status..results }}"
  ignore_errors: yes`

This?

Answer (score 0):

Try "{{ status.results.content }}"

Comment: fatal: [SERVER]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'content'"}
...ignoring
`

Comment: You missed the fact that `status.results` is a list.

Comment: what do you mean?